# Increase progress bar each second -- error

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

it's my first experience with C#, I'm trying to make a progress bar that increases each second on a value (a part of program, it receives current value from another object and sets it to the progress bar).

My simplified object source:

```
public delegate void LoadingProgressChanged(int percents);
public event LoadingProgressChanged loadingProgressChanged;

public void Enable()
{
    loadingTimer = new Timer(1000);
    loadingTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(IncreaseLoadingPercentage);
    loadingTimer.Start();
}

private void IncreaseLoadingPercentage(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    loadedPercents += getLoadingPercentsPerSecond();
    loadingProgressChanged(loadedPercents);
}
```

Form sources:
In constructor

```
router.loadingProgressChanged += new AbstractRouter.LoadingProgressChanged(percentageChanged);
```

Body of percentageChanged

```
public void percentageChanged(int percs)
{
    progressBar1.Value = percs;
}
```

And I get error

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was
>   created on.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

I understand why it happens: it seems that percentageChanged form is called in timer thread. But how to implement it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Check out this tutorial on [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar). It shows how to update a `ProgressBar` control from a `BackgroundWorker` and the example even uses `Thread.Sleep` to update it every nth of a second. Sounds pretty damn close to what you're trying to do, while also probably being a little closer to a real world example of updating and using a progress bar and background workers.

Comment: search in the upper right hand corner.  Search for "accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"

Comment: You should probably just use the WinForms.Timer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
public void percentageChanged(int percs)
{
   Invoke(new Action(() =>
   {
     progressBar1.Value = percs;
   }));
}
```